# Is it safe to use conditional rendering for private data in react for only authorized users

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, jwt

I'm building a react app and have set up an API server in node to authenticate users (I'm using JSON web tokens for persisted access and MongoDB as database for reference). I, therefore, wondered if it would be safe to store a state in redux like "isLoggedIn" to use as a reference to perform conditional rendering to. My initial thought was that this information would still be public if a potential intruder managed to change the redux state of "isLoggedIn" to true because react isn't serverside rendered. Is this true in react?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should never send sensitive information to an unauthenticated client. Once the client has de information, the intruder can change the react code, or even see the info stored in "state" with browser dev-tools

Answer (score 0):

Having an `isLoggedIn` state is fine. Your backend should be protected against requests from users who are not logged in anyways so you shouldn't be displaying sensitive data.

If an attacker was able to change the isLoggedIn state, they'd still need to make the necessary API requests to see the sensitive info. Those API requests should be protected by the JWT that you generated when logging in.